# OptiFine is freezing fluid animations. How do I fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

So, on OptiFine, when I pour down a bucket of water, it starts flowing, like it should. The thing is, the flowing water is not animated. In my animation settings (under video settings), Water Animated is set to ON. What is causing the water to stay still, and how do I make it animated?
(This is on OptiFine HD G9_pre16 Ultra. (1.17))
This also applies to lava and fire.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that other people have had with OptiFine 1.17. It has been fixed in the newer preview.

The 1.17 version of OptiFine is still in preview, so bugs like this are expected. Just go back to the downloads page on optifine.net and download the latest preview, or if it has fully released by the time you read this, download the non-preview version.